# How to set java-7-oracle as default java version?

Tags: java

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

I tried to install oracle-java7 on my Linux Mint with the codes above. After executing those codes, I tried to check if its working by typing "java -version" but suddenly an error occured.

```
bash: /usr/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install a package to set (and keep) oracle-java7 as the default; or you can manually set the java alternative with `update-java-alternatives`. Something like,

Option 1. `sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default`

Option 2. `sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-7-oracle`

Comment: i tried to do the 1st option but still when i type "java -version" the error is still there

Comment: Run `update-java-alternatives -l` and see what is currently configured.

Comment: java-7-oracle 1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle

Comment: thats what comes out when i type update-java-alternatives -l